# flutter-firestore: how to delete item n days old from listview

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to get items over 10 days old automatically deleted from listview in a page of my flutter-firestore app. Here is my code to create that listview.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('notifs')
          .orderBy('notifTimestamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('Loading...');
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ...
 ]))}
```

How can I get a list item over 10 years old deleted automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save `'notifTimestamp'` in the `Date` variable in `Firestore` from `Dart`.

```
    DateTime tenDaysOld=DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 10));

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('notifs')
          .orderBy('notifTimestamp', descending: true)
          .startAt([tenDaysOld]).snapshots();
```

Comment: Thanks Amon, I saved `'notifTimestamp'` with this code; `'notifTimestamp': FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()`. How can I save this `'notifTimestamp'` in the `date` variable?